# about pointer and reference

Tags: c++, linux

I have a pointer `*p` and a reference `&s`. I would like all the values that `s` contains to be copied by `p`. How can I do this?

Need some code example. THX

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  What do you mean "copied **by** p"?  What is wrong with `*p = s`?

Comment: so i have to do:*p=s? i didn't know that:d. thx a lot:)!

Comment: pointer to what? reference of what?

Comment: "values that contain s"? Do you mean members of the object referenced by s? There is no way to find all objects that contain a reference to s.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a lot less than clear.  But for now, I'll give you this:

```
*p = s;
```

If this doesn't answer your question, then you need to clarify exactly what you're after.